# I'm not getting the right answer about the error java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial

Tags: android

> 12-04 15:17:30.362 2132-2132/com.example.umairkhan.test1
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.example.umairkhan.test1, PID: 2132
>                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.umairkhan.test1/com.example.umairkhan.test1.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
>   com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from
>   ProcessRecord{c9488ec 2132:com.example.umairkhan.test1/u0a57}
>   (pid=2132, uid=10057) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or
>   android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening
>   provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from
>   ProcessRecord{c9488ec 2132:com.example.umairkhan.test1/u0a57}
>   (pid=2132, uid=10057) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or
>   android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
>                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3550)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2018)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1468)
>                                                                                  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:475)
>                                                                                  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.example.umairkhan.test1.MainActivity.fetchContacts(MainActivity.java:38)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.example.umairkhan.test1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
>                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Have you added the permission `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` or `android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS` in your manifest?

Answer (score 1):

LogCat clearly shows that **java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial** that requires requires **android.permission.READ_CONTACTS** or **android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS**

Add this 2 lines in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```